# How do I see memory allocation in a given .NET application?

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management, heap-memory

I need to check how much memory is allocated in the heap. Is there a way to get this value programmatically with C#?

I know about the `System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(...)` but that only tells me the size of an object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a [PerformanceCounter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter.aspx) you can query the "# Bytes in all Heaps", from your own process, and even other processes.

Use the Category ".Net CLR Memory" to see a lot of counters available.

You have to see what the difference in system load is between the PerformanceCounter and the GC.GetTotalMemory that is proposed by Jon Skeet.

Answer (score 4):

Does [`GC.GetTotalMemory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.gettotalmemory.aspx) do everything you need?

(Note that `SizeOf` only tells you the *marshalled* size, too - not necessarily the size in memory.)

Comment: Sweet. Do you also know know how to get the amount of instances of some particular class that has been instanciated as well?

Comment: @Spoike: No, I don't believe that information is available without running under the profiling API.