# Memory usage + .net

Tags: .net

Is there a way in .net 2005 ide to find out the memory usage by variables inside a function and when their memory is made free by garbage collector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part of your question:

You can use a number of tools to profile the memory foot print of your application - down to individual lines of code. I can recommend the following tools:

- [CLR profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms979205.aspx) (free download from Microsoft)
- [ANTS Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/Products/ants_profiler/index.htm) from RED Gate (commercial but great GUI)

For second part:
GC in .net is not deterministic. It is called automatically when there is no free memory for the application. There is no tool which will tell you when GC has released memory back to free store.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625465/how-do-i-see-memory-allocation-in-a-given-net-application), which has a few approaches including

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(...)
```

You can look at [GC.RegisterForFullGCNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.registerforfullgcnotification.aspx) to see how to watch the garbage collector

Comment: That only returns the unmanaged memory size, not the managed size.

Comment: Actualy i was looking for something like callstack, watch etc and not by writing code. Is there any option within the IDE to track memory allocations

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're asking here.  If you're looking for the memory footprint of a particular object, the best way to go is WinDbg and the SOS extension.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb190764.aspx

This can give you a multitude of information about the object heap including size and generational information.

This post here goes into detail about how to use WinDbg to get the size of an object graph.  It may be what you're looking for

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/articles/20060114.asp

Comment: Actualy i was looking for something like callstack, watch etc and not by writing code. Is there any option within the IDE to track memory allocations

Comment: @Strike, windbg is a debugger and doesn't require any code.  There is no way to actually track an allocation in the IDE currently.